# Parsley Config Error Messages

Tags: parsley.js

I'm trying to override the default error messages using windows.ParsleyConfig, but I have yet to find the correct syntax:

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
            messages: {
                defaultMessage: "This value seems to be invalid.",
                type: {
                    number: "asdasd."
                }
            }
        };
```

I've tried a few variations of this, non of which has worked. The code is being called before parsley.min.js is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `ParsleyConfig.i18n.en` (assuming you're using the default locale `'en'`), not `ParsleyConfig.messages`.

```
// After Parsley has loaded:
window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.en.type.number = "hello";
```

Alternatively, for most error messages, you can specify them in options:

```
<form data-parsley-required-message="Hey, fill this in!">
```

Comment: I had experimented with changing the default catalog, but I'm not really sure how to structure it. My basic test was: window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.en = {
            type: {
                 number: "hello"
            }
        }

Comment: That overwrites all error messages though, probably not what you want. Answer edited.